# Angular, Node, NVM, and NPM

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, nvm

I installed Node version v6.5.0 a few days ago and with this installation came npm v3.10.3.

Today I updated Node to v8.9.4 using `nvm install 8.9.4` and it came with corresponding version of npm (can't remember the exact version number).

Here are my questions:

1. After installing Node 8.9.4, I listed all Node versions and it shows both versions correctly. I then do `nvm use 8.9.4` and output shows as -> `Now using node v8.9.4 (64-bit)`.

   However, when I do `node -v`, it still shows v6.5.0 and not v8.9.4 that I switched to. Why? It should show v8.9.4
2. How do I change version of npm from v3.10.3 (that came with Node v6.5.0) to the latest version (that came with v8.9.4)?
3. How do I list all npm versions on my machine?
4. Will Angular CLI v1.7.0 work with both Node v6.5.0 and v8.9.4?

Comment: Did you install the first version of Node with nvm? If you didn’t, uninstall it.

Comment: No, I installed it using .msi file.

Comment: Okay, so you can use Add/Remove Programs to uninstall that version of Node, then manage everything using nvm in the future.

Comment: So I need to install nvm first then. Where can I download it from?

Comment: Ah, my mistake – nvm doesn’t support Windows. It would be better to just install 8.9.4 using the .msi, then.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may "use" the node version you want:

   ```
   $ nvm use 8.9.4
   ```

   but, if you want to set it as default:

   ```
   $ nvm alias default 8.9.4
   ```
2. When using the version of node you want, just run:

   ```
   $ npm install -g npm
   ```
3. NVM have "node" versions: `nvm list`. For each version of node, there is a npm version associated. You need to `use` (step 1) each one and run `npm -v'
4. Don't know.